# Jackrabbit how are indexes created and updated ? how are the index files updated?

Tags: sling, jcr, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

We are using jackrabbit oak with mongodb as document store and s3 as blob store. The content we are currently storing is mostly text and very few images. But the size of s3 is around 80 GB whereas the size of mongoDb is only ~10 GB . I've lucene indexes enabled. I assume oak stores the indexes, revision files in s3. Can someone explain how this works? what is the 80Gb content that oak is creating in s3?